# App crashes due to IllegalArgumentException : com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow

Tags: java, android

On the basis of webservice response I am deciding to open activity.

```
if(getCompanyByUser().size() > 0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, SelectCompany.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

**getCompanyByUser()** is this method where I am calling webservice.

```
private ArrayList<CompApp> getCompanyByUser() {
    final ArrayList<CompApp> list = new ArrayList<CompApp>();
    showpDialog(pDialog);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getCompByUser,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.e("response",response);
                    try{
                        CompApp[] access = new Gson().fromJson(response, CompApp[].class);
                        for (CompApp c : access) {
                            list.add(c);
                        }

                        helper.addCompany(list);
                        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss");
                        String dateString = formatter.format(new java.util.Date());
                        saveSharedPref(SplashScreenActivity.this, "timestamp", dateString);
                    }catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Unable to process request.\nTry again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    hidepDialog(pDialog);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Internet not connected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    hidepDialog(pDialog);
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams() {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            User user = new Gson().fromJson(getSharePref(SplashScreenActivity.this, "user"), User.class);
            String lastUpdated = getSharePref(SplashScreenActivity.this, "lastUpdated");
            params.put("appCode","PCA001");
            params.put("userId",user.id);
            params.put("timestamp",""+lastUpdated);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(SplashScreenActivity.this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    return list;
}
```

Now In this list is always null because it is being filled in background. So Now It will always open SelectCompany activity.

I have two problems my app is crashing due to `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` and I want program should wait till list get filled.

Here is `logcat`

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42130a30 V.E..... R......D 0,0-456,144} not attached to window manager
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:370)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:84)
at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:337)
at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:320)
at com.ashishkudale.linksolution.common.CommonMethods.hidepDialog(CommonMethods.java:27)
at com.ashishkudale.linksolution.SplashScreenActivity$11.onResponse(SplashScreenActivity.java:339)
at com.ashishkudale.linksolution.SplashScreenActivity$11.onResponse(SplashScreenActivity.java:321)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5127)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: show your manifest file

Comment: Can you put `hidepDialog` method. The problem is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flow of the code is incorrect here. When you call getCompanyByUser(), it is an async call. Hence you need to wait for its response before your proceed.

So simply call `getCompanyByUser()`. Change its return type to void because that is not required since it is an async call. Now, You should start your activities in onResponse and ErrorResponse callbacks.

```
private void getCompanyByUser() {
//....
@Override
public void onResponse(String response) {
 // ...
//Once the list is made start new activity
if(list.size() > 0) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
} else {
    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, SelectCompany.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
}
```

Comment: thank you. now I am very clear about web services call.

Answer (score 0):

you have the issue with only your return. You are returning before your list get populated in `onResponse()`, as `onResponse` is asynchronous so you don't wait for it and return an empty list. Second, exception is because you are doing some dialog thing (you will be holding reference of your activity) in response of your `onResponse()` method but the current activity is already finished so the exception thrown.
Best solution is use a Handler, with message of success and failure. send callback to handler in your response/failure and in your handler's `handleMessage(Message msg)` decide which activity should start.

Something like this:
in your activity make a handler like this

```
Handler handler =new Handler() { 
    @Override 
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
      // you may check success or failure on msg based. 
      // handle your next activity check here
    } 
  };
```

and in your `onResponse()` or `onFailure()` send a message to handler like 
`handler.sendEmptyMessage()` or `handler.sendMessage(msg)`